# IntegrityError at /job/create/ NOT NULL constraint failed: core_job.category_id

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm creaating an `api` that user can create a job. when I want to test it with postman and create a job I have this error:

```
 IntegrityError at /job/create/
NOT NULL constraint failed: core_job.category_id
```

how do i can fix it ?? I'm using generic `CreateAPIView`

models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=300, unique=True, help_text='write in English.')
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Job(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=400, unique=True, allow_unicode=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    image_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='products_pic/%Y/%m/%d/', null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    phone1 = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True, blank=True)
    phone2 = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True, blank=True)
    phase = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    daily_start_work_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    daily_end_work_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    popular = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views:

```
class JobCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = JobSerializer
    queryset = Job.objects.all()
```

serializers:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__'


class JobSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = '__all__'
        lookup_field = 'slug'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'lookup_field': 'slug'}
        }

    def get_category(self, obj):
        return obj.category.name
```

Comment: @Sumithran core is my app name and Job is my model

Answer (score 0):

The category field is not populating with any value when you create the job. I mean category field is Null when you save that form. I am not sure but any way the problem is related to category field